# How to change criteria for sorting in jQuery slider?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I'm trying to edit template of this theme for Wordpress theme: http://demo.fabthemes.com/financio/
At the "From the blog" container, i don't want to show all the latest entries.
Since i'm on my learning path, i don't need an exact solution. I just need somebody to point me in right direction.

Question:
How can i change my code so that slider will show entries from specific rubric?
I feel like i need to change something in

`"$the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();"`

```
<div id="timer1" class="timer"></div>
 <div id="carslide">
  <?php $the_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=9' );
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
 <div class="post slidepost" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
   <?php
      $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
      $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
      $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 300, 150, true ); //resize & crop the image
   ?>
<?php if($image) : ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
   <img class="slide-image" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/>
  </a>
<?php endif; ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
  <?php wpe_excerpt('wpe_excerptlength_index', 'wpe_excerptmore'); ?>
  <div class="clear">
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "from specific rubric"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to change the `WP_Query('posts_per_page=9')` part so that it displays posts that match a different query. You can read the [reference for queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) for more information.

For example, if you wanted to show the five latest posts from a particular category, you would use `WP_Query('posts_per_page=5&cat=3')`.